# display results in search engine (no MySQL)

Tags: java, search-engine

I am developing a search engine in java.It works fine but all results are displayed in one page.How can I display results in separate pages like google. If I have 100 results then the results will be displayed in say 10 pages 10 results each. I am not using MySQL. My data is stored in files.

Comment: Just curious as to why you choose to store your data in files. If you don't want a separate server process for your database, you could consider using a self-contained, serverless database like SQLite.

Comment: I don't need a database,there is no concurrency problem or any other problems, what I need is to read data from file no writing is needed.Accessing directly from file is faster for my system.

Comment: Parse the file and put the items in an array/list. Use the solution proposed by enhzflep to locate the range of items to be displayed on each page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to take the specified page number and use that to work out which result to display first in that page.

say your URL looked like this

```
www.yoursite.com?search=JSP&page=3
```

Then, you'd extract the search term and find the results. You'd also get the requested
page and use it.

```
firstResultNum = page * resultsPerPage
for (i=firstResultNum; i<firstResultNum+resultsPerPage; i++)
{
  displayCurSearchResult(i);
}
```